# PyQt: get the current QTreeWidget item

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreewidgetitem

I presently have a QTreeWidget named 'treeWidget', and for the life of me, cannot figure out how to get the index value or the text of the selected treeWidget branch.

self.treeWidget looks like:
User
-Inbox
-Sent
-Drafts
-Trash

I need to know which branch is selected so I can display folders in the branch's corresponding file folder.  I've been trying to understand the Qt documentation, but I'm totally stumped by the C++. And the PyQt docs don't have any examples.  I've searched everywhere for three days trying to tinker and figure out the answer but keep coming up with errors.

The closest I think I've come is something like this:

```
self.connect(self.treeWidget,SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.loadAllMessages)

def loadAllMessages(self, folder):
    item = self.treeWidget.currentItem()
```

Do I need to setSelectionMode first or something?  All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This

```
#remove the old way of connecting
#self.connect(self.treeWidget,SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), self.loadAllMessages)
self.treeWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.loadAllMessages)
def loadAllMessages(self, folder):
    getSelected = self.treeWidget.selectedItems()
    if getSelected:
        baseNode = getSelected[0]
        getChildNode = baseNode.text(0)
        print getChildNode
```

Comment: Can I also get the index number of the selected child this way?  It seems like I can't just substitute '.indexOfChild' for '.text'. The PyQt docs say "int indexOfChild (self, QTreeWidgetItem achild)", but I don't know what I should put as the QTreeWidgetItem achild part...

Comment: You need to use indexFromItem to find it. Something like itmIndex =self.treeWidget.indexFromItem(baseNode)

Comment: Hmmm...tried <pre>print self.treeWidget.indexFromItem(baseNode)</pre> but it kept spitting out "<PyQt4.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x7f891bbfd398>". Tried changing different things but couldn't get it to work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Following **Achayans** answer and comments, you get the index as a QModelIndex by using `.indexFromItem()`. To retrive now the real index, you need to use `.row()` which is described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmodelindex.html) and shown in the following code:

```
self.treeWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.loadAllMessages)
def loadAllMessages(self, folder):
getSelected = self.treeWidget.selectedItems()
if getSelected:
    baseNode = getSelected[0]
    qmIndex = self.treeWidget.indexFromItem(baseNode)
    itemIndex = qmIndex.row()
    print('Selected index: ', itemIndex)
```